# How do I bind a local function when I pass a rendered view interacting with that function to a prop in react-native?

Tags: react-native, accordion, native-base

I'm passing a render to the Accordion element in native-base using the `renderContent` prop. The render contains two buttons, which, when pressed, run functions that are local to the current component. Unfortunately those functions are not available once it has been actually rendered.

How do I bind the functions properly so that when pressed, the correct functions are referenced?

I'm using the most modern stable releases of react-native, native-base, and I'm running this through expo for testing.

Here's the documentation on native-base:

http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#accordion-custom-header-content-headref

Accordion:

```
<Accordion
  dataArray={ this.state.websites }
  renderContent={ this._renderAccordionContent }
/>
```

renderContent:

```
_renderAccordionContent(content) {
  return (
    <Button 
      onPress={() => this.openSite(content.path)}
    >
      <Text>Open</Text>
    </Button>
    <Button
      onPress={() => this.editSite(content.key)}
    >
      <Text>Edit</Text>
    </Button> 
  )
}
```

When the buttons are pressed, the expected results are that the functions are run.

The actual results are that when the buttons are pressed, these errors are populated:

```
_this2.openSite is not a function.

_this2.editSite is not a function.
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried binding them in the constructor?  How are you defining your functions in your class?

Comment: @Andrew I don't have access to the `Accordion` constructor. It's a native-base component. Is there a way for me to extend a native-base component like in PHP? Also, I'm defining the functions in my component just like the ES6 `render()` class is defined here: 

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this excellent article that shows several different ways of binding your functions https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Here is an example of binding it in the constructor of your component that uses the Accordion component. It is by no means the only way of binding the functions. The above article gives 5 different ways of doing it.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.openSite = this.openSite.bind(this);
    this.editSite = this.editSite.bind(this);
  }

  // I am assuming you have written your functions like this and not as arrow functions
  openSite (path) {
    ...
  }

  editSite (key) {
    ...
  }

  _renderAccordionContent(content) {
    return (
      <Button 
        onPress={() => this.openSite(content.path)}
      >
        <Text>Open</Text>
      </Button>
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.editSite(content.key)}
      >
        <Text>Edit</Text>
      </Button> 
    )
}

  render() {
    ...
    <Accordion
      dataArray={ this.state.websites }
      renderContent={ this._renderAccordionContent }
    />
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I attempted your solution (and each of the solutions listed in the article you included) but the errors were the same: `_this2.editSite is not a function. (In '_this2.editSite(content.key)', '_this2.editSite' is undefined)` Maybe I'm not understanding what question I should be asking.

Comment: I also implemented your solution on `_renderAccordionContent` and then it seemed to fire correctly. I figured that since I was passing the function into a component, that had functions passed into it, I should probably "climb the tree" all the way up. That seems to have solved it. Thanks!